# What kind of math is this and how do you solve it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you solve this question, and what kind of math is it? I've never seen it before so I don't even know how to begin! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: **Hint:** Linear Algebra, specifically - matrix multiplication. Step 1. Do the dimensions of the two matrices work such that multiplication is defined? Step 2. If so, multiply the two matrices.

Comment: This kind of math is called *linear algebra*, or [*matrix multiplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: hint: there may be a chapter on this topic in your math book.

Comment: John Joy: there wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just matrix multiplication. What you need for it to work is that the dimension of the row for $A$, matches that of the column for $B$. This is due to the fact that matrix multiplication is just a bunch of dot products. So mathematically, this amounts to saying,

$$(a_{i,1},...,a_{i,n}) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} b_{1,j} \\ b_{2,j} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n,j} \end{pmatrix}$$

i.e $A \in \mathcal{M}(m \times n) \Rightarrow B \in \mathcal{M}(n \times l)$. In words this means, if $A$ has $n$ columns, then $B$ must have $n$ rows.

Comment: Your explanation, though very exact, is much above the level of the question of the OP.

Comment: When I learned linear algebra, the question about when matrix products was defined became immediate when I realized that I was just taking dot products with rows of one matrix and columns of another. This is the insight I wanted to share. Rather it is advanced or not, the OP gets a better variety of answers to choose from.

Comment: I understand what you say. **But** understand that you have centered your explanation on the concept of "dot-product" which is a completely abstract word, (as if  i said you wreath product and you just don't know the axioms of a group) for somebody who is maybe still in high school, and with chinese language, notwithstanding the extraodinary difficulty to unerstand doubly indexed formulas.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Read the bio of the OP. They are taking Chinese and he/she is American. My attempt here is to not just answer this question for the OP, but future questions about matrix products. If that means the OP will have to learn a few more terms, then so be it. That's just the life of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

It's linear algebra. It asks for the product $AB$ of the matrices $A$ and $B$ (if it is defined, which it is; it is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-30 & 23 \\
-6 & 22 \\
24 & -22
\end{bmatrix}$$).